# How to change Xcode sdk compiling version

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I have tried to build an app through to the AppStore but they rejected it due to the app using sdk 11.4. Stating that it needs to use the updated version of 12.1. 
The current Xcode I have installed is 10.1 or 10B61 which is the latest without making use of a Beta. I have searched through the settings trying to find how to update the sdk as well as maybe target that newer base SDK.

Things I have tried:

- Searched for newer Xcode (stated above)
- Searched through settings for the base SDK version number so it can be changed.
- Went to AppStore to find any updates for Xcode (there were none)
- Tried googling how to change/update the sdk, but none give an explicit answer on where this can be done. It merely states that Xcode 10 should come with a base SDK of 12.1, but that does not seem to be the case here.

Please note that this is not to target the minimum version. I know where that is and it is set accordingly. No issues there.

---

**EDIT:**

I have run $> xcodebuild -showsdks and it shows that sdk 12.1 is the sdk that is installed.
However, it seems that it is somehow overriding it to 11.4 when it is trying to build to AppStore. Not sure why.

Comment: Is this Objective-C or Swift?

Comment: React-Native (latest)

Comment: @JeremyP, i found the issue, please see answer from myself below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue did not seem to be with Xcode itself but rather Bitrise that we were using to build and publish the app to the AppStore. Once the correct stack was selected for the building/publishing, it managed to build, however, we then found a different issue.

Using Xcode 10.1 we built the app in iOS 12.1, however, Bitrise seems to have an issue with React-Native third-party dependencies when it comes to Xcode 10.0+. It just doesn't seem to install them correctly and throws an error while compiling. (dependency: double-conversion)

The only advice we could find online was to downgrade xCode to 9.4 and then manually add the Device Support files (from targeted SDK to 12.1) to the app. This is something we don't want to do.

We are waiting for Bitrise to sort their stuff out, but in the meantime, we are looking into building straight from Xcode or Fastlane.